# JMeter - Maintaining a global counter

Tags: jmeter, thread-safety, counter

I'm trying to write what sounds like a simple task of maintaining a thread safe global counter by calling the following global function;

```
${__counter(FALSE,)}
```

If I run with 100 threads, each thread will have a unique count returned by the function (i.e. from 1 to 100), however each thread seems to keep that same counter variable no matter how many loops it does. i.e. thread 1 has the count still set as '1' on it's second iteration, rather than '101'.

How do I get that counter to update on each loop? It's important that it does this as it appends this counter to a 16 digit user defined starting value, so that the concatenated number is unique for every transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue using "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and latest stable [JMeter 5.6.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-update-jmeter-56)

[image]

As per design "global" [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) returns an incremented value each time it's being called, the question is where did you place the function.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm using JMeter 5.4.2 (corporate restriction). Using a normal Thread Group with JSR223 Pre Processor. It seems if I place the same code in a BeanShell PreProcessor the count does correctly implement for each loop.

Comment: Using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 5.4.3 you're supposed to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). See [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more details. If you're using variable or function inside the script it might be cached and you will see the same value for subsequent iterations. See [documentation on the JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

Comment: Hi Dmitri. If I add a debug sampler under the thread group like you have done, I can see the counter incrementing on each loop in the results tree. However if I add a JSR223 Pre Processor using Groovy and do a `log.info (${__counter(FALSE,)}.toString())` just afterwards, it's static for each iteration (for some reason '2', rather than '1'). I would rather not use Beanshell but that's the only way I can access that incrementing counter to do some code manipulation on it.

Comment: Ah - I should have read the link you send me properly :) . If I uncheck the 'Cache complied script if available' setting within the JSR223 Pre-Processor, it does correctly implement the count. Thank you - appreciate your help

Comment: You can [initialize your counter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-counter) like `${__counter(FALSE,counter)}` and then use `vars.get('counter') as int` in Groovy script. Alternatively you can programmatically invoke [IterationCounter.execute()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/functions/IterationCounter.html#execute(org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult,org.apache.jmeter.samplers.Sampler)) 

Unchecking `cache compiled script` disables script compilation and caching feature so Groovy engine evaluates the script each time.

Answer (score 0):

This is where having a commercial tool really shows versus an open source one.  Every commercial tool has the ability to define a parameter (no code needed) that is "iteration" as well as one that is "Virtual User Number".